# How can I map enum properties to int in ServiceStack.OrmLite without using annotations?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I want to serialize class from third party library. So I can't use annotations. How to configure ORMLite to serialize all (or specified) enums as int ?

Edit:
I found a solution. I register a converter for a given type:

```
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.RegisterConverter<MY_ENUM_TYPE>(new 
ServiceStack.OrmLite.Converters.Int32Converter());
```

But unfortunately it cannot be set globally for all enum types.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far and what was the result of each attempt.

Answer (score 0):

ServerStack has a bunch of [ReflectionUtils](https://docs.servicestack.net/reflection-utils) and one of them, Type.AddAttributes(), is a short hand for adding attributes to types at runtime.

With a simple test using an Enum from an external assembly I was able to scan for all Enums within that Assembly and attach the EnumAsIntAttribute.

I followed this up with a quick test to ensure it inserted into the database as an integer.

```
// Test class containing external enum.
public class Test
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public ExternalEnum? EnumValue { get; set; }
}

// Use ExternalEnum type to get it's Assembly grab all export Enums.
IEnumerable<Type> types = typeof(ExternalEnum)
    .Assembly
    .GetExportedTypes()
    .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum)));

// Loop through exported enums and add EnumAsIntAttribute.
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    type.AddAttributes(new EnumAsIntAttribute());
}

// Create Test table in DB.
db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Test>();

// Save to DB.
db.Save<Test>(new Test 
{ 
    EnumValue = ExternalEnum.SomeValue
});
```

Edit: Fixed incorrect enum type used when assigning to EnumValue in db.Save.